On the uniqueness of matrix representation under changes of basis
I am reading this paper. In light of this post, we should have the following fact:
For a finite dimensional vector space $V$ (over $\mathbb{R}$) with basis $\{v_1,\dots, v_N\}$ and for a linear map $L:V\to V$, the unique matrix representation $(l_{ij})_{i,j=1,\dots,N}$ should implicitly be defined as
$$
Lv_j = \sum_{i=1}^N l_{ij} v_i
$$
Intuitively, we look at what the map $L$ does to a basis element and represent it in our given basis.
That is exactly what the authors of the paper write on page 23.
Indeed, one can also look at the matrix representation of a slightly altered basis, namely for
$\{v_1/\epsilon, \dots, v_N/\epsilon \}$ for $\epsilon > 0$. Looking at the defining equation for the matrix representation $(l^\epsilon_{ij})_{i,j=1,\dots,N}$, we have
$$
L(v_j/\epsilon) = \sum_{i=1}^N l^\epsilon_{ij} v_i/\epsilon.
$$
Using the linearity of $L$ and the two equations above, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N l^\epsilon_{ij} v_i/\epsilon = \sum_{i=1}^N l_{ij} v_i/\epsilon.
$$
By the properties of a basis, and since this works for any $j$, we must have $(l^\epsilon_{ij})_{i,j=1,\dots,N} = (l_{ij})_{i,j=1,\dots,N}$. Hence, the matrix representations do coincide.
Denoting these two representations by $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{L}^ {(\epsilon)}$ (by the above they are equal), we must also have that the spectral norm of a Matrix is invariant under such simple changes of basis (multiplying by a scalar). Hence, the spectral norms satisfy $\|\mathbf{L}\|_2 = \|\mathbf{L}^{(\epsilon)}\|_2$.
However, on page 23 of the paper, the authors claim, that we have $\epsilon\|\mathbf{L}\|_2 = \|\mathbf{L}^ {(\epsilon)}\|_2$.
Question: Am I missing something or did I do something wrong? Or is the claim by the authors false? More generally, is there maybe a different change of basis where we actually have $\epsilon\|\mathbf{L}\|_2 = \|\mathbf{L}^ {(\epsilon)}\|_2$?

$\mathbf L^\epsilon$ suggests you are raising $\mathbf L$ to some power--$\mathbf L^{(\epsilon)}$ is better notation.  If you follow their argument and introduce results from an intro to linear algebra course: write $S\mathbf L^{(\epsilon)} S^{-1} = \mathbf L $ but $S= \epsilon \cdot I$ which commutes with $\mathbf L$ so $\mathbf L^{(\epsilon)} = \mathbf L$.  In general the spectral norm isn't preserved under change of basis but at least in cases of $S$ commuting with $\mathbf L$ (as well as unitary $S$) then it is.  The notation and wording choices indicate that is a physics not math document

Thanks for the comment, I understand. Also changed the notation in my post as suggested.
